# Azure B2C One Time Password redirection

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm new to azure b2c. I can't figure out why azure b2c gets redirected to a page which is an app outside the b2c environment instead of showing the error when user reaches the OTP retry limit.

The OTP retry limit is set to 11 and after that it gets redirected to an app page and doesn't show the error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is your custom policy or technical profile configured ?